# How to Load WhatsApp Sticker from firebase?

Tags: java

Problem Description
How to Load Stickers Packs from firebase?

Links
Already I've been through -
https://github.com/idoideas/StickerMaker-for-Whatsapp
https://github.com/viztushar/stickers-internet

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to make a class with the sticker properties, a provider and a couple more things before loading the stickers from firebase(you can easily know how to retrieve data from firebase, it's the same for any data, so im going to skip that step)..

**A dynamic WAStickers app should have following Characteristics:**

- Content Provider for necessary Details
- It should Send an Intent to Whatsapp Sharing necessary details about the Sticker Pack All the
- images must be in (or converted to) webp format

**Why it should have a Content Provider?**

A content provider is a class that sits between an application and its data source, and its job is to provide easy access to the underlying data source. This data can also be accessed by other applications on your device.

To provide necessary information about the StickerPack to WhatsApp you need to create a class called StickerPack which will hold the following parameters.

```
class StickerPack implements Parcelable {
    String identifier;
    String name;
    String publisher;
    String trayImageFile;
    final String publisherEmail;
    final String publisherWebsite;
    final String privacyPolicyWebsite;
    final String licenseAgreementWebsite;

    String iosAppStoreLink;
    private List<Sticker> stickers;
    private long totalSize;
    String androidPlayStoreLink;
    private boolean isWhitelisted;

    StickerPack(String identifier, String name, String publisher, String trayImageFile, String publisherEmail, String publisherWebsite, String privacyPolicyWebsite, String licenseAgreementWebsite) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.name = name;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.trayImageFile = trayImageFile;
        this.publisherEmail = publisherEmail;
        this.publisherWebsite = publisherWebsite;
        this.privacyPolicyWebsite = privacyPolicyWebsite;
        this.licenseAgreementWebsite = licenseAgreementWebsite;
       }
    }
```

For additional information about this class follow the [Link](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerPack.java).

This class also contains an ArrayList of Stickers, where Sticker is defined by the following class.

```
package com.example.samplestickerapp;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.List;

class Sticker implements Parcelable {
    String imageFileName;
    List<String> emojis;
    long size;

    Sticker(String imageFileName, List<String> emojis) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
        this.emojis = emojis;
    }

    protected Sticker(Parcel in) {
        imageFileName = in.readString();
        emojis = in.createStringArrayList();
        size = in.readLong();
    }

    public static final Creator<Sticker> CREATOR = new Creator<Sticker>() {
        @Override
        public Sticker createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Sticker(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Sticker[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Sticker[size];
        }
    };

    public void setSize(long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(imageFileName);
        dest.writeStringList(emojis);
        dest.writeLong(size);
    }
}
```

**Creating the Content Provider**
For creating the content provider, first step is to:

**Get permission to use the ContentProvider:**
In the Android Manifest we should ask for a read/write permission to use the content provider. It’s a security feature which informs the user of what the app actually does.

```
<provider
        android:name=".StickerContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />
```

Where `${contentProviderAuthority}` will be replaced by the authority name of your content provider.

**Create a Class that extends ContentProvider**
**URI — Uniform Resource Identifier:** URI is used to specifically identify or give the location of some data on your phone.

This location is how you know exactly what type of data we’re querying for. The location is build from 3 parts:

- (1) content:// — The content provider prefix
- (2) The content authority — specifies which Content Provider to use
- (3) Specific
  data — a string that identifies exactly what data in the Content
  Provider we’re interesting in accessing.

In our Content Provider we need to mention 4 URI’S as mentioned here.

First, In the onCreate method of your ContentProvider class, create a URI Matcher object and add the URI’s to the object. **Before going through the below code snippet read about Uri Matcher from the [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher).**

Now since you are familiar with URI matcher you must be familiar with how to use it

- First, we build a tree of Uri Matcher object.
- Then we pass the Url to getType function which matches it against our URI
  Let’s perform the first step here.

  private static final UriMatcher MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
      static final String METADATA = "metadata";
      private static final int METADATA_CODE = 1;
      private static final int METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK = 2;
      private static final int STICKERS_CODE = 3;
      static final String STICKERS_ASSET = "stickers_asset";
      private static final int STICKERS_ASSET_CODE = 4;
      private static final int STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE = 5;

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreate() {
      final String authority = BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY;
      if (!authority.startsWith(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getPackageName())) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("your authority (" + authority + ") for the content provider should start with your package name: " + getContext().getPackageName());
      }
      MATCHER.addURI(authority, METADATA, METADATA_CODE);
      MATCHER.addURI(authority, METADATA + "/*", METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK);
      MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS + "/*", STICKERS_CODE);

      for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
          MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS_ASSET + "/" + stickerPack.identifier + "/" + stickerPack.trayImageFile, STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE);
          for (Sticker sticker : stickerPack.getStickers()) {
              MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS_ASSET + "/" + stickerPack.identifier + "/" + sticker.imageFileName, STICKERS_ASSET_CODE);
          }
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```

Here in the above method we have added a Uri pattern to our MATCHER object, now we need to match this pattern and return the exact UrI which will the location of sticker data on our device. Next the Url hit by WhatsApp is passed to the getType function to match it against our Uri’s and return the specific location of data on our device.

```
@Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        final int matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (matchCode) {
            case METADATA_CODE:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + METADATA;
            case METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + METADATA;
            case STICKERS_CODE:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + STICKERS;
            case STICKERS_ASSET_CODE:
                return "image/webp";
            case STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE:
                return "image/png";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
```

Next, depending upon the Url we call the query method which will match the Uri and return a cursor object for the specific Uri.

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final int code = MATCHER.match(uri);
        if (code == METADATA_CODE) {
            return getPackForAllStickerPacks(uri);
        } else if (code == METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK) {
            return getCursorForSingleStickerPack(uri);
        } else if (code == STICKERS_CODE) {
            return getStickersForAStickerPack(uri);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
```

*Cursors are iterators that provide read/write access to the data of a Content Provider.*

See the getPackForAllStickerPacks(), getCursorForSingleStickerPack() and getStickerPackInfo() function from [here](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerContentProvider.java). To know the type of data to be provided by the Cursor Object.

**Congratulations!!** By now you have reached your first milestone. So far we have learnt:

- What are Content Providers?
- What type of Data do we send via ContentProviders?
- How do we process the Uri’s to give a specific Cursor object?

If you can answer these questions then Congrats!! You have done a wonderful job. If not then I would suggest you to read about ContentProviders and UriMatcher’s to get a proper understanding.

After that, you just need to load the content from firebase, which should have the same structure on your class.

Source: [Link](https://medium.com/bobble-engineering/dynamic-whatsapp-stickers-part-1-android-2ac00dc57111)

Comment: How would we update the sticker pack . I read that we need to upgrade the image_data_version . It works but I need to send it whatsapp which will show that pack with xyz name already exists and when i check the sticker in whatsapp it gets the new stickers in the pack. I need to skip the sending part which invokes whatsapp intent. It seems we can update it directly in content provider.